# How to Iterate JSON properties in TypeScript

Tags: json, angular, typescript

My question is very simple, I have a following JSON Typescript Object and I like to Iterate trought the JSON properties

`{"work_type":"Fabricación","work_type_resp":"Mesa","looking_for":"Relación Calidad/Precio","image":"https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/online-quotation-images/153366018967.png","width":"22","high":"34","depth":"","modifications":"mod"}`

The code used is the following angular TypeScript component:

```
export class DetailsOnlineQuoteModalComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() title;
  @Input() values:string;
  properties:JSON;

  constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.properties=JSON.parse(this.values);
    console.log(this.properties);
  }

}
```

What I really need is to go through the key-value attributes of the JSON and show them in my HTML.

Many Thanks!

Comment: where do you want to access keyvalue pair in html or ts?

Comment: Hi, In the HTML

Comment: [There is no such thing as a JSON (TypeScript) Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are using angular 6.1 use keyvalue pipe

```
<div *ngFor="let title of data | keyvalue">
  {{title.key}}
</div>
```

For Angular 5

```
<div *ngFor="let key of dataKeys">
  {{key}} ------------- {{data[key]}}
</div>
get dataKeys() { return Object.keys(this.data); }
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/keyvalue-pipe-qtaqnm

Comment: I'm using angular 5

Comment: Please add to your answer how you made `dataKeys`

Comment: answer for angular 5 is also working for Angular 9 ( keyvalue not working as well)

Comment: Hi Chellapan, actually I got an error when using the model to initiate the object data.(or person in my example / please have a look here for more details => https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular9-iterate-on-object-attribute)

Comment: As mentioned in the doc:https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe#input-value, You have to use Interfaces to describe Indexable Types. Change your interface as follows export class Person{
  [key: string]: string,
  name:string;
  surname:string;
  location:string;
  age:string;
}

Answer (score 5):

As per your comment, I'm assuming you want to do an ngFor on the HTML to display each one of the key-value pairs

```
<div *ngFor="let key of Object.keys(properties)">
  {{properties[key]}} --> this is the value
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get all the keys using Object.Keys and assign to a variable as follows,

```
this.properties=JSON.parse(this.values);
let response = Object.keys(this.propertie);
```

now you can use ngFor over it,

```
<div *ngFor="let key of response ">
  {{properties[key]}}  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

### component.ts

```
let obj = {"work_type":"Fabricación","work_type_resp":"Mesa","looking_for":"Relación Calidad/Precio","image":"https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/online-quotation-images/153366018967.png","width":"22","high":"34","depth":"","modifications":"mod"}

this.keyOfObj = Object.keys(obj);
```

### html

```
<div *ngFor="let key of keyOfObj ">
  {{obj[key]}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately seems to be NOT working (with keyvalue) with ANGULAR_9

see here for a comparison of full different way of doing: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular9-iterate-on-object-attribute

otherwise the answer by defining a method to do the job is still working.