# Iterables such as Arrays in Ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

i'm tring to fect from webservice an API in json. I'm using this code in my service provider:

```
getAll() {
return this.authHttp.get(this.cfg.apiUrl + this.cfg.books)
  .toPromise()
  .then(rs => {
    return Array.of(rs.json());
  });
```

}

and from the module:

```
  this.booksService.getAll().then(books => this.books = books);
```

but when i try to iterate book of books i trown this error:

NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

someone can help me to figure out?

Comment: Try to console.log books, you will see that it isn't what you think it is :)

Comment: the problem is that i console object books coming fine

Comment: So it's an object ? "NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays" but Object != Array :)

Comment: can u try with this.booksService.getAll().then(books => this.books = JSON.parse(books));

Comment: can you share your console object?

Comment: if the response is object you can use keyvalue pipe 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51732524/how-to-iterate-json-properties-in-typescript/51732597#51732597

Comment: same result. The strange thig is that if i change i Laravel ->paginate(15) to ->get() method it work like a charm.

Comment: please add what JSON.stringify(rs.json()) looks like